# Making Sushi on Shabbos

Tags: shabbat, food

I'm trying to find the status of making sushi on shabbos.

I will ask LoR, but would also like to get info here as well as sources, and use as a guide for others.

Issues I'm aware of / heard of:

- Mevashel - Obvious, let the rice cool first (also pretty painful).
- Boneh - Not really 
  sure why it would be, but heard some people throwing it around.
- Memachaik/Memareach - while spreading the rice. Don't think it applied to ready-to-eat food though.
- Tochen - Cutting some veggies very thinly could pose an issue (such as cucumber) can be avoided by preparing from before.
- Uvda D'chol  - So is making a sandwich, or using the toilet. Not sure why this is more than anything else.
- Measuring - simply; don't.

Any ideas/sources would be appreciated.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26100/is-sushi-muktzeh

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/26100/5323; relevant: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/4712/5323

Comment: http://hirhurim.blogspot.com/2010/04/new-periodical-rjj-journal-no-lix.html is a well done article

Comment: @DoubleAA Can't find actual article

Comment: @boruch It's in the book. צא ולמד.

Comment: Rav Asher Weiss gives a shiur about this topic. https://minchasasher.com/shiur/shulchan-aruch/5777-makking-sushi-sabbos/

Answer (score 4):

According to [DinOnline.org](http://www.dinonline.org/2014/02/13/can-you-make-sushi-on-shabbat/) one may make sushi on Shabbos, however the rice should not be very hot.

Comment: Thanks @Gershon Gold.
I found that too, but no sources, reasoning or even an author are provided

Comment: [Here is the list of Rabbi's that are part of DinOnline](http://www.dinonline.org/the-kollel/rabbis-of-the-institute/)

Comment: @boruch The reasoning for not wanting the rice to be too hot could be that hot rice actually cooks the surrounding fish and vegetable matter.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [OU's daily halacha](https://oukosher.org/halacha-yomis/is-it-permissible-to-make-sushi-on-shabbos-is-it-muktza/),

> Shulchan Aruch (Orach Chaim 308:32) writes that unsalted raw fish is
>   muktza, because it serves no purpose on Shabbos. However in our days,
>   if one has cuts of raw fish that are edible as sushi, then they are
>   not muktza. However, Rav Belsky, zt”l, questioned whether one may make
>   sushi on Shabbos. The Chayei Adam 39:1 writes that the melacha of
>   boneh (building) applies to food as well, and that attaching foods
>   together to produce a desired picture or shape, is included in this
>   prohibition. Since shaping sushi might be included in this
>   prohibition, Rav Belsky, zt”l, recommended that one should not make
>   sushi on Shabbos with the intent of making a specific design or
>   pattern.

There was also an article on this topic in the RJJ Journal ([description](http://hirhurim.blogspot.com/2010/04/new-periodical-rjj-journal-no-lix.html)).

Comment: I was going to cite that RJJ article, so thank you for saving me the effort of finding it.  I don't understand its argument that building a maki roll is boneh but building a sandwich isn't, but so be it.